# Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.Nil$ List()

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My scala code goes like this.

```scala
def getFileName(fileName: String, postfixList: List[String]): String = {
  if (...) {
    return fileName + postfixList(0)
  }
    return fileName + postfixList(1)
}

val getFileNameUdf = udf(getFileName(_: String, _: List[String]): String)

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val postfixList = List("a", "b")
  val rawFsRecordDF = sparkSession.read.option("delimiter", "\t").schema(fsImageSchema)
    .withColumn("fileName", getFileNameUdf(col("name"), lit(postfixList)))

}
```

For each of column values, I want to append a certain postfix.

Running this code, I get

> diagnostics: User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.Nil$ List()

How should I pass list to a UDF function?

Any comment or link would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lit` is good for basic types. For parameterized types, you should use `typedLit`.

```scala
val rawFsRecordDF = sparkSession.read.option("delimiter", "\t").schema(fsImageSchema)
    .withColumn("fileName", getFileNameUdf(col("name"), typedLit(postfixList)))
```

should work.

Comment: For the starters like me, I got `value typedLit is not a member of object org.apache.spark.sql.functions` error, which was a version issue. It seems that 2.2.0+ is required.